# Overriding fetch() for PDO when fetching using foreach

Tags: php, oop, pdo, php-5.3

I have extended [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) and modified the [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method to typecast values of the types timestamp and arrays, in PostgreSQL, to DateTime and native array. This works as intended but I can't override the behaviour when using the statement in a foreach.

I have solved this by returning rows into an object implementing ArrayAccess, IteratorAggregate and Countable. However I'm not satisfied with that solution and just want a pure array back.

Example:

```
class ExtendedStatement extends PDOStatement {
    protected function __construct() {
        $this->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    public function fetch(
        $fetch_style = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        $cursor_orientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT,
        $cursor_offset = 0)
    {
        $r = parent::fetch($fetch_style, $cursor_orientation, $cursor_offset);
        if (is_array($r)) {
            $r["extradata"] = TRUE;
        }
        return $r;
    }
}
$db = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");
$db->setAttribute(
    PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array("ExtendedStatement", array($db)));
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE example(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR)");
$db->exec("INSERT INTO example(name) VALUES('test')");

// This is what is does
$s = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM example");
$s->execute();
foreach ($s as $r) {
    var_dump($r);
}
$s->closeCursor();

// This is how I want it to be
$s = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM example");
$s->execute();
while ($r = $s->fetch()) {
    var_dump($r);
}
$s->closeCursor();

// This is how I want it to be
$s = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM example");
$s->execute();
var_dump($s->fetch());
$s->closeCursor();
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["extradata"]=>
  bool(true)
}
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["extradata"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code that does work as expected, and does not work as expected?  If you've overridden `fetch`, it should always work "correctly."

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: Does it work normally when you replace the foreach with `while($r = $s->fetch()) {`?  Also, keep in mind that the result returned by the `parent::fetch` call may well not be an array, it could be null.  You should probably add an `is_array` check or something similar.

Comment: Yes it works as expected. My normal code works, but this starts looping to infinity. This code is just an example to demonstrate the bevaviour. This is not the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PDOStatement` class implements the built-in internals-only `Traversable` interface. The iterator that it implements bypasses the public `PDOStatement::fetch()` method.

Comment: I have realised this already, but I still want to hack into it in some way. I had an idea of implementing Iterator, but abandoned it in hope of a better solution.

Comment: @antennen: Well, you have three choices really: 1) patch `ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c`, 2) use `while` instead, 3) implement your own iterator. Regardless, I would probably recommend you to file a bug at http://bugs.php.net. It seems reasonable enough that it should call the public `fetch()` method.

Comment: Bug reported: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52444. I might try the own iterator approach for now.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
$sql = 'select * from table';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

So the only thing you have to do is set some options :)

Comment: Given that he already has that kind of code in the examples in his question, I'm pretty sure he is aware of that possibility.